# Should I delete my own question after a silly mistake?

Tags: discussion

I asked this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26703684/undefined-reference-to-foofoo?noredirect=1#comment42000632_26703684

And the only problem I got in the code was that I forgot a semicolon(silly me).
But should I keep this question, or delete it. I was thinking about deleting it because, I guess that it isn't helpful for anyone else.

Comment: yes sir, why not!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yeah, you might as well. Otherwise, chances are it'll get closed. We have a close reason for:

> This question was caused by **a problem that can no longer be reproduced** or **a simple typographical error**. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the [shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

Comment: And *hopefully* the roomba will be able to delete it later... if you didn't.