# Should I answer my own question if I made a mistake even if it got upvotes?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737646/change-property-of-this-when-unit-testing-angular-controller-after-controller).

After finally managing to get plunker to work (I comment that it wasn't working for me at the time of writing the question), I was able to prove what I was asking for was, in fact, possible. I had just made a typo in my source code.

Normally I would just delete my question at this point, because it no longer seems relevant.

**However**

It got 4 upvotes fairly quickly, meaning that other people found this question interesting (or maybe it was just a well asked question?).

Because of this, and the fact that I wasn't able to find it myself, I answered my own question (to hopefully aid anybody else that looks for this).

My question is related to [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275923/should-i-delete-my-own-question-after-a-silly-mistake), which suggests closing it, but that question isn't about closing your question despite it getting upvotes.

My question is, if my question received a few upvotes, but turned out to be a typo, should I answer my own question along the lines of:

> For anyone interested, it is in fact possible to do this.
>
> I have added a plunker proving it (link to plunker)

?

Comment: self answers are a thing, and if you can provide a comprehensive and nice self answer, that is very much welcome.

Comment: @Magisch true enough, but this is a typo / cannot reproduce no?

Comment: If its really only a typo then you may as well delete it though, or wait for it to get closed. You'd lose 20 rep, but ah well.

Comment: But surely this prevents someone else from asking the same question in the future? Maybe I could change my question to "Is it possible to do x?" Then the answer can be along the lines of "Yes it is possible to do x"?

Comment: @MattLishman: You can't really know _why_ your question got upvoted. Maybe some people upvoted it just for it's proper formatting or clean presentation.

Answer (score 4):

You should ask yourself: "Will my post be useful for anyone else in the future?", and you'll probably conclude that it won't.

I would have deleted it without worrying about the votes I got, many others will come if you keep it up with good posts.

Comment: I am not bothered about the reputation, my point was more that if it was upvoted, people might find it useful. I think the question is useful to others, but if people disagree, I guess a mod can close it?

Comment: @MattLishman Maybe the upvotes were before knowing it's a typo.

Comment: Does it make a difference that there wasn't a typo with any of the code I posted, just a typo in my own source code?